# Mysql error 150 on column rename

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, alter-table

I've an old db with columns'charset to latin1

Now i'm trying to change the whole db in utf8, i've made a script to change all the tables in utf8 like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `mytable` CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

and all the columns like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `mytable` CHANGE `mycolumn` `mycolumn` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

But on some columns (primary keys and constraints, i guess) i'm getting this error:

```
Error on rename of './test/#sql-5028_217b96' to './test/mytable' (errno: 150)
```

Anyone knows how to get around this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most likely your `mycolumn` is a part of a foreign key. If so, you have to remove the constraint, then change type for the both primary/foreign key and then add constraint again.

Comment: I just ran into a similar problem (going from an `INT` to a `BIGINT`). I decided to duplicate the table (which had a foreign key constraint on the column I needed to change) and its content, change the column type in the duplicate table without issue, and then replaced the original table with the duplicate table. Is that a dangerous thing to do?

Comment: @tylerl No, if the data on the original table remains unchanged during your changes. Otherwise you can have data loss/inconsistency.

Comment: Yeah I believe it broke things in my app... Something must have not copied over right when the table was duplicated (I'm using Sequel Pro on a Mac)? I don't think any data was lost, but suddenly my server didn't feel like saving data to a particular table anymore! Weird... The problem is that I had made a note that the field in question was a foreign key in a particular table, but I can't find the FK constraint! Grrrr....

Comment: Anybody knows of any tool that is able to automate this? For a large database being refactored it is crazy to perform these operations manually.